# Is 150 Euro in my pocket enough to have 6 days food at Rennes city, France?

Tags: france, food-and-drink

Is  150 Euro in my pocket enough to have 6 days food at Rennes city, France?

Of course I will prefer low budged food like bread, rice, biriyani, chicken or eag etc?

Comment: Would I be correct in understanding from the last paragraph that you'll have access to cooking facilities?

Comment: You can use https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/in/Rennes to help figure that out.

Comment: What's tolerable to eat, and how much is required, will differ greatly because of eater's food preferences, as well as the eater's size and appetite. Thus, I think this question is both too broad and opinion-based. I voted to close.

Comment: How will you  prepare the food?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Rennes has four Lidls, https://www.lidl.fr. They all have bakeries.

150 euros buys you about 450 croissants, or about 25kg of tzatziki, or about the same amount of moussaka. In other words, you can eat about 4kg of moussaka every day for 150 euros in six days, without overshooting your budget.

Comment: While at LIDL, buy pasteque and feta cheese as well...taste sooooo good in the parc.

Comment: There are many other shops, where they have traditional French food, which are hardly more expensive and give a much more satisfying experience.

Comment: Buy bread pudding from the boulangerie.

Comment: what is croissants?

Comment: A [croissant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croissant) is a very typical pastry found in French bakeries.